# I am getting unexpected output from this code:

Tags: java, netbeans

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
       int i = 0;
       int x;
       x=input.nextInt();
       int y;
       y=input.nextInt();
       while(i<y){
        for ( i = 1; i <=y; i=i+x) {
            for ( int j = i; j <=(i+(x-1)); j++) {
                 if(x%2==0 && y%3==0)
                 {
                     System.out.print((j-1)+" ");
                 }
                 else
                     System.out.print(j+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Sample input:

```
3 99
```

This is the output I am supposed to get :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
...
97 98 99
```

But when I give my input as

```
4 99
```

The output I get is :

```
0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 7 
....
96 97 98 99
```

I am not supposed to start with 0.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Hint: the problem is in `System.out.print((j-1)+" ");`

Comment: `j` starts at `1`, and you print `j-1`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: You don't need the while loop in there.

Comment: If I remove (j-1) I am getting an extra number ie; 100 at the end of the output which I don't want...I want it to stop at 99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to rewrite your code a little so that it isn't so messy. Is this what you want to achieve?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=input.nextInt();
    int y=input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i < y + 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        if (i % x == 0){
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    int x;
    x=input.nextInt();
    int y;
    y=input.nextInt();

     for( i = 1; i <=y; i++) {
                  System.out.print(i);
                  System.out.print(" ");
                  j++;
        if(j == x){
             System.out.println();
             j = 0;
        }
     }
```

you can use this code to output as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your first output is going to be a 4 because at that time x = 3 and y = 99. Neither are even so your else block will be hit. Change `if(x%2==0 && y%3==0)` to `if(x%2==0 || y%3==0)` and you will get 0 for the first output. That won't totally fix your problem but it will get you on the right path.

Answer (score -1):

You begin `j=1` (because i = 1 the first time you enter the loop)
and if `x%2 == 0` (which is the case) you print `j-1`
of course you will begin with 0, I don't see why you're surprised.
if you want to avoid that, just print :
`(j-1)==0 ? "" : j-1 + " "`

Comment: I begin with j = i not j = 1

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: and if I change to i = 0 I get my output starting from -1

Comment: @DimitriBosteels I tried (j-1)==0 ? "" : j-1 + " " but for input : 4 99 it's giving me only 3 numbers on the first line and then it starts giving 4 number from the next line

Comment: Well, 99/4 isn't an Integer, so you cannot have all lines with 4 numbers. Either the first one is 3 or the last one. I told you why you get a 0, I told you how to avoid it, but if you want to begin to 1 and have the last line with 3 numbers, you will have to rework your loops